# React routes has bugs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i noticed that the bootstrap components causing the bug, the postcomment navbar link works if i used original react tags (the NavLink in the commented out section), but if i use bootstrap components (Nav.Link) postcomment link doesnt work anymore. does anyone know why and how do i fix it?

```
    <Route
              path="/postcomment"
              element={
                logInState ? (
                  <PostComment />
                ) : (
                  <Navigate to="/signin" />
                  // <SignIn />
                )
              }
            />
    
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { Container, Nav, NavDropdown, Navbar, NavbarBrand, Button, Offcanvas } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    const NavigationBar = ({ logInState, handleLogout }) => {
        return (
            // <div>
            //     <NavLink to="/" >Home</NavLink><br />
            //     <NavLink to="/takeaway" >Takeaway  Menu</NavLink><br />
            //     <NavLink to="/takeawaychinese" >Takeaway Chinese Menu</NavLink><br />
            //     {logInState ? (
            //         <>
            //             <NavLink to="/postcomment">Post comment</NavLink><br />
            //             <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button><br />
            //         </>
            //     ) : (
            //         <>
            //             <NavLink to="/signup">Sign up</NavLink><br />
            //             <NavLink to="/signin">Sign in</NavLink>
            //         </>
            //     )}
            // </div>

        <Navbar className="bg-body-tertiary custom-navbar" collapseOnSelect expand="lg" Navbar sticky='top' bg="dark" data-bs-theme="dark" >
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                    <img
                        src="../../public/logo192.png"
                        alt="Logo"
                        width="30"
                        height="30"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top"
                    />
                    Logo
                </Navbar.Brand>

                {/* appear when minimized */}
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />

                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="me-auto justify-content-between" >
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href='/takeaway'>Takeaway Menu</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href='/takeawaychinese'>Takeaway Chinese Menu</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href='/aboutus'>About Us</Nav.Link>

                        <NavDropdown title="Comment" id="responsive-nav-dropdown" align="end">
                            <NavDropdown.Item href='/commentlist'>Comment list</NavDropdown.Item>

                            {logInState ? (
                                <>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="/postcomment">postcomment</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                    <NavDropdown.Item onClick={handleLogout} className="dropdown-item" id='dropdown-item-button'>Logout</NavDropdown.Item>
                                </>
                            ) : (
                                <>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="/signup">Sign up</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="/signin">Sign in</NavDropdown.Item>
                                </>
                            )}
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>


            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

export default NavigationBar

Comment: My guess is that after you authenticate and try to navigate to `"/postcomment"` the `logInState` hasn't updated yet, and so the user is bounced to `"/signin"`, but by now the `logInState` *has* updated and authenticated users get bounced to `"/"`. Where do you handle logging users in? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the logInState update is asynchronous and the navigation is triggered before the state is updated properly. This can happen if the login state update is delayed or if there's a race condition.

```
// ProtectedRoute.js
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProtectedRoute({ element, requireAuth, ...rest }) {
  // Logic to determine whether the user should be authenticated
  if (requireAuth && !logInState) {
    return <Navigate to="/signin" />;
  }

  return <Route {...rest} element={element} />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Then, in your main App component, you can use the ProtectedRoute wrapper like this:

```
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';

// ...

<ProtectedRoute
  path="/postcomment"
  element={<PostComment />}
  requireAuth={true} // Require authentication for this route
/>
```

Comment: i need to include logInState as a prop to make it work
<ProtectedRoute
        path="/postcomment"
        element={<PostComment />}
        requireAuth={true} // Require authentication for this route
        logInState={logInState}
      />
and now it got stuck on the signin page before log in (all nav links redirects me back to signin page)
after logged in it causes an error (A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).